# How to find processes that are using a COM interop component

Tags: c#, com, interop

I have many applications (ASP .NET, WCF, etc) on a server that are holding a reference to a 3rd party COM interop component, and I'd like to find out which processes are doing so. Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure that would be possible unless you could change the source code in the COM component.

Comment: If the component is a DLL, then you can use `Module32First` et al to enumerate all DLLs loaded into all processes. This way you can find processes that have your special DLL loaded.

Comment: Thanks Igor. I actually just fired up Process Explorer to help me track down which processes were using the specified DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Process Explorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to track down which processes were using the specified DLL.